# create-react-app hangs when performing GET request for registry.npmjs.org/react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am trying to create my first project with `create-react-app`, however it hangs on this spinner below thats just a period spinning in a circle next to `react`.

```
> npx create-react-app github-finder --verbose

Creating a new React app in C:\dev\react-training\github-finder.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

yarn add v1.12.1
verbose 0.2505522 Checking for configuration file "C:\\dev\\react-training\\github-finder\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.251879 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Users\\rizers\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.2541254 Found configuration file "C:\\Users\\rizers\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.2556172 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\etc\\npmrc".
verbose 0.2563122 Checking for configuration file "C:\\dev\\react-training\\github-finder\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.256965 Checking for configuration file "C:\\dev\\react-training\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.2575825 Checking for configuration file "C:\\dev\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.2660975 Checking for configuration file "C:\\dev\\react-training\\github-finder\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.2670012 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Users\\rizers\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.2683534 Found configuration file "C:\\Users\\rizers\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.2701472 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\etc\\yarnrc".
verbose 0.2721652 Checking for configuration file "C:\\dev\\react-training\\github-finder\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.2730678 Checking for configuration file "C:\\dev\\react-training\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.2738477 Checking for configuration file "C:\\dev\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.2810919 current time: 2021-02-26T19:14:21.831Z
verbose 0.4244942 Performing "GET" request to "https://yarnpkg.com/latest-version".
[1/4] Resolving packages...
verbose 0.5258425 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.npmjs.org/react".
⢀ react
```

My current version of Node is 14.16.0 and my current version of React is 7.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears a very simple command option fixed my problem. I noticed in the `create-react-app` docs that [there is an option to use npm](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/#selecting-a-package-manager) when building the React application, specifically `--use-npm`. Adding this answer in case someone else frantically googling this issue like I was has the same issue.